# Find the length of the longest valid parenthesis sequence in a string, in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming, code-complexity

My friend ran into a question in an interview and he was told that there is an O(n) solution. However, neither of us can think it up. Here is the question:

There is a string which contains just `(` and `)`, find the length of the longest valid parentheses substring, which should be well formed.

For example `")()())"`, the longest valid parentheses is `()()` and the length is 4.

I figured it out with dynamic programming, but it is not O(n). Any ideas?

```
public int getLongestLen(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
        return 0;

    int len = s.length(), maxLen = 0;
    boolean[][] isValid = new boolean[len][len];
    for (int l = 2; l < len; l *= 2)
        for (int start = 0; start <= len - l; start++) {
            if ((s.charAt(start) == '(' && s.charAt(start + l - 1) == ')') && 
                (l == 2 || isValid[start+1][start+l-2])) {
                    isValid[start][start+l-1] = true;
                    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, l);
                }
        }

    return maxLen;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about counting parentheses? When you add 1 to the counter for each `(` and subtract 1 for each `)`?

Comment: Counter examples for the DP solution: any valid sequence with length not equal to power of 2 (`()()()`) and any valid sequence that can't be generated by addition of single parenthesis pair to another valid sequence (`(())(())`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did this question before, and it is not easy to come up with O(n) solution under pressure. Here is it, which is solved with stack.

```
   private int getLongestLenByStack(String s) {
    //use last to store the last matched index
    int len = s.length(), maxLen = 0, last = -1;
    if (len == 0 || len == 1)
        return 0;

    //use this stack to store the index of '('
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '(') 
            stack.push(i);
        else {
            //if stack is empty, it means that we already found a complete valid combo
            //update the last index.
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                last = i;        
            } else {
                stack.pop();
                //found a complete valid combo and calculate max length
                if (stack.isEmpty()) 
                    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i - last);
                else
                //calculate current max length
                    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i - stack.peek());
            }
        }
    }

    return maxLen;
}
```

Comment: Just had a test and it works! It is a great solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I was having a hard time figuring out how to do this and despite using a stack was missing out on how to make sure we add a previous sequence to the current one if they become adjacent. This makes it clear

Comment: @Sid I am glad it's helpful to you

Answer (score 4):

We need to store indexes of previously starting brackets in a stack.

We push the first element of stack as a special element as "-1" or any other number which will not occur in the indexes.

Now we traverse through the string, when we encounter "(" braces we push them, else when we encounter ")" we first pop them and

If stack is not empty, we find length of maximum valid substring till that point by taking maximum of result(initialised as zero) and the difference between current index and index at top of the stack.

Else if stack is empty we push the index.

```
int result=0;
stack<int> s1;
s1.push(-1);
for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i)
{
    if(s[i]=='(')
        s1.push(i);

    else if(s[i]==')')
    {
        s1.pop();

        if(!s1.empty())
            result=max(result,i-s1.top());
        else
            s1.push(i);
    }
}
cout<<result<<endl;
```

Here 's' is the string and 's1' is the stack.

Comment: Good answer nice use of push and pop

Comment: By far the best and easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can increment/decrement an int variable for each open-parenthesis/close-parenthesis respectively. Keep track of the number of such valid operations (where the variable doesn't go below 0) as the current length, and keep track of the longest-such as the max.

```
public int getLongestLen(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return 0;       
    }

    int stack = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (Character c: s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(') {
            stack++;
        }
        if (c == ')') {
            stack--;
        }
        if (stack >= 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (stack < 0) {
            counter = 0;
            stack = 0;
        }
        if (counter > max && stack == 0) {
            max = counter;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: @axiom I think 'incorrect' depends on your definition of valid parenthesis sequence, which wasn't completely clear here. I was using the (somewhat standard) interpretation: starts from 0 (i.e. the first `(`), and ends at 0. This is why there's a `stack==0` end clause. So `(()` rightly produces 0 as the length. If you're familiar with the [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) problem, this would be a 'valid' mountain range--one which starts and ends at sea-level, as in this [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#mediaviewer/File:Mountain_Ranges.png).

Comment: Otherwise, if you just want to keep track of the longest sequence *until* it becomes in valid, you can just take the `counter` value at that point (before resetting it to 0). I can show that if you're interested.

Comment: I don't see anything not clear here. The desideratum is the length of the longest valid parenthesis sequence, which has only one definition. The answer here should be 2, as `()` is the longest valid sequence. You are solving a different problem, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, This is incorrect. This does not really answer the question that was asked. It is solving some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

ALGORITHM:  [Entire code on GitHub](https://github.com/harishvc/challenges/blob/master/stack-longest-matching-parenthesis.py)
1. Add to stack
   1.1 initialize with -1,handle )) without ((
2. When you see ) pop from stack
   2.a if stack size == 0 (no match), push current index values
   2.b if stack size > 0 (match), get max length by subtracting index of value at top from current index (totally wicked!)

```
def longestMatchingParenthesis(a):
    pstack = []        #index position of left parenthesis
    pstack.append(-1)  #default value; handles ) without ( and when match adds up to 2!
    stack_size = 1 
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if a[i] == '(':
                    pstack.append(i) #Append current index
                    stack_size += 1
            else:    # handle )
                    pstack.pop()
                    stack_size -= 1
                    #determine length of longest match!
                    if stack_size > 0:
                            #difference of current index - index at top of the stack (yet to be matched)
                            result = max(result, i - pstack[-1])
                    else:
                            #stack size == 0, append current index
                            pstack.append(i)
                            stack_size += 1 
    return result

a = ["()()()", "", "((((", "(((()", "(((())(", "()(()" ,"()(())"]
for x in a:
    print("%s = %s" % (x,longestMatchingParenthesis(x)))

#output
()()() = 6
= 0
(((( = 0
(((() = 2
(((())( = 4
()(() = 2
()(()) = 6
```

Comment: This gives 4 for "()(()" but the correct answer is 2

Answer (score 1):

O(n) can be achieved without the conventional use of stacks if you are open to a dynamic approach of finding a valid element and then trying to increase its size by checking the adjoining elements .
Firstly we find a single '()'
Then we try to find a longer string including this :

## The possibilities are:

- (**'()'**) where we check an index before and an index after
- **'()'**() where we check the next valid unit so that we don't repeat it in the search.

Next we update the start and end indices of the current check in each loop

At the end of the valid string ,check the current counter with the maximum length till now and update if necessary.
Link to code in Python on GitHub [Click Here](https://github.com/niranjan233/Longest_Valid_Braces).

Answer (score 0):

just came up with the solution, do comment if there is anything wrong

```
count = 0 //stores the number of longest valid paranthesis
empty stack s
arr[]; //contains the string which has the input, something like ())(()(
while(i<sizeof(arr))
{
    if(a[i] == '(' )
    {
        if(top == ')' ) //top of a stack,
        {
            count = 0;
            push a[i] in stack;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(top == '(' )
        {
            count+=2;
            pop from stack;
        }
        else
        {
            push a[i] in stack;
        }
    }
}
```

print count

Answer (score 0):

The solution below has O(n) time complexity, and O(1) space complexity.


It is very intuitive. 
We first traverse the string from left to right, looking for the longest valid substring of parens, using the 'count' method that is normally used to check the validity of parens. While doing this, we also record the maximum length of such a substring, if found. 
Then, we do the same while going from right to left.


The algorithm would be as follows:

```
// Initialize variables

1. count = 0, len = 0, max_len_so_far = 0


// Check for longest valid string of parens while traversing from left to right

2. iterate over input string from left to right:
   - len += 1
   - if next character is '(',
         count += 1
   - if next character is ')',
         count -= 1
   - if (count == 0 and len > max_len_so_far),
         max_len_so_far = len
   - if (count < 0),
         len = 0, count = 0


// Set count and len to zero again, but leave max_len_so_far untouched

3. count = 0, len = 0


// Now do a very similar thing while traversing from right to left
// (Though do observe the switched '(' and ')' in the code below)

4. iterate over input string from right to left:
   - len += 1
   - if next character is ')',
         count += 1
   - if next character is '(',
         count -= 1
   - if (count == 0 and len > max_len_so_far),
         max_len_so_far = len
   - if (count < 0),
         len = 0, count = 0


// max_len_so_far is now our required answer

5. Finally,
   return max_len_so_far
```

As an example, consider the string

```
"((())"
```

Suppose this string is zero-indexed.
We first go left to right.
So, at index 0, count would be 1, then 2 at index 1, 3 at index 2, 2 at index 3, and and 1 at index 4. In this step, max_len wouldn't even change, because count is never 0 again.
Then we go right to left.
At index 4, count is 1, then 2 at index 3, then 1 at index 2, then 0 at index 1. 
At this point, len is 4 and max_len_so_far=0, so we set max_len = 4.
Then, at index 0, count is 1.
At this point, we stop and return 4, which is indeed the correct answer.
A proof of correctness is left as an inclusive exercise to the reader.

NOTE: This algorithm could also be very simply tweaked to return the longest valid substring of parentheses itself, rather than just its length.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="))((())";
    String finalString="";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

         if (s.charAt(i) == '('&& s.charAt(i+1) == ')') {
         String ss= s.substring(i, i+2);
         finalString=finalString+ss;
        // System.out.println(ss);
         }

    }
    System.out.println(finalString.length());
}
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Try adding some extra detail. Why does this code work?

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic Programing to Store and re-use already computed results

```
def longest_valid_paranthesis(str):
    l = len(str)
    dp = [0]*len(str)
    for i in range(l):
        if str[i] == '(':
            dp[i] = 0
        elif str[i-1] == '(':
            dp[i] = dp[i-2] + 2
        elif str[i - dp[i-1] - 1] == '(':
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + 2 + dp[i - (dp[i-1] + 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static int LongestvalidParentheses()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        string str = "()()))()";
        char f = '(';
        char s = ')';
        var chararr = str.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (chararr[i] == f)
            {
                if (chararr[i + 1] == s)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).